# How to test aryphmetic operations in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Have one question about writing unit tests for calculations. Are there other ways of writing test for Test method. Writing such unit test seems to me useless cause we just copy logic to test and compare it

```
public int TestMethod(bool flag)
{
    var result = default(int);
    var someConstant = 1400;

    if (flag)
    {
        result = (someConstant * 5) - 20;
    }
    else
    {
        result = someConstant - 50;
    }

    return result;
}


[Test]
public void TestMethod_ReturnsResult_WhenFlagIsTrue()
{
    var someConstant = 1400;
    var expctedResult = (someConstant * 5) - 20;

    var actualResult = TestMethod(true);

    Assert.IsTrue(expctedResult == actualResult);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean arithmetic? I googled "aryphmetic" and it just suggested arithmetic.

Comment: This is an odd case because it's not clear why the arithmetic is in the method in the first place. You could replace the whole method with `public int TestMethod(bool flag) => flag ? 6980 : 1350;` (Probably replace those with constants) This would make more sense if `someConstant` was also a parameter, not a constant. Then you would write unit tests that passed in a value, and checked for correct results. The unit tests would just contain the expected results - they wouldn't calculate them by repeating the code in the method being tested.

Answer (score 0):

You should not copy arithemtic operations to test your method. This can introduce bugs. It's better to save it as constant.

If you do not want to test arithmetic logic then extract those arithmetic operations outside and inject them inside via DI. Inside your tests you would only need to check which of the methods was invoked for the given flag. You can do it easilly with `Moq` framework for example.

```
public int TestMethod(bool flag)
{
    const int someConstant = 1400;

    if (flag)
    {
        return someService.CalculateWhenTrue(someConstant);
    }
    else
    {
        return someService.CalculateWhenFalse(someConstant);
    }
}
```

Then decide if it's worth to test single operations in those methods.

Comment: You mean move ariphmetic oerations to separate service in test project?

Comment: After some thought it might be good or not good depending on complexity of arithmetic operations. With that you will be able to test easily whether good method is called and test will work even when you change the way arithmetic calculations are done.

It's always something.